# How do I put a line break between each log in the xcode console?

Tags: xcode, nslog

Reading the `NSLog()` statements in the console is difficult because it takes me a while to parse out the different statements.  Is there a way to automatically have some line break between each `NSLog()` call's resulting log?

Answer (score 2):

How are you reading the console log?

Every `NSLog` *does* produce a seperate line in the console log - as viewed in Xcode, the Console app, or by listing the log file directly in the Terminal.

If you wish to add extra line breaks into an `NSLog` message you can use the standard C escape `\n` in the format string, e.g.:

```
NSLog(@"First line\nsecond line");
```

HTH

**Addendum**

From your comment the following might help:

```
#define MyLog(fmt, args...) NSLog(fmt "\n\n", args)
```

This macro will expand to a call to NSLog with an added line break - note you need *two* `\n`'s, that isn't a typo. **This will only work if the format is a literal string** (two adjacent literal strings are concatenated by the compiler).

Define that in a project-wide header and then find/replace `NSLog` with `MyLog` and I think you might have what you wish.

Comment: Maybe I should have been clearer.  I meant an additional line break so there is a one line gap between all logs.  The massive dump of mem address, formatting and class structure on a black background with no spacing really is hard on the eyes.  I could add a `\n` to each log but thats a lot to remember, I was wondering if there is a way to modulate the default logging behavior from `NSLog()`.  I suppose I could create my own function that calls NSLog and pass in a modified string..

Comment: @user5797668 - I see, added an addendum.

Comment: one of the main instances i want this modified log is in logging out the current view during a touches moved sequence which by definition takes a `%@` format specifier, would that work?

Comment: @user5797668 - the macro will work regardless of the format specifiers it contains, it won't work if the format comes from an `NSString` variable, the format must be a literal string, `@"..."`.

Comment: ah ok I see, so something like `NSLog(@"%@", touch.view);` would work because of the `@""` part..